# TensorFlow 'global_step' variable not getting updated for exponential decay

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have a network where I am using exponential decay of the learning rate. For this I'm keeping track of a 'global_step' TF variable that gets incremented by 1 in every batch that's processed. However, looks like in reality, it's not really getting updated. Here's the code.

```
...
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='global_step')
starter_learning_rate = 0.01
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate, global_step, 1000, 0.50)

update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    optm = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost, global_step=global_step)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


def train(file):
    global global_step
    for batch in batches:
        global_step += 1
        ...        
    return loss

...
global_step = 0
for epoch in EPOCHS:
    for f in files:
        loss = train(f)
```

The global_step within the function and outside is getting updated. But my learning rate doesn't change. When I attach a summary to my TF global_step variable, I see that it remains constant at 0.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I haven't seen where do you set **learning_rate** variable, but this is the way how to use it:

## define global step variable

```
global_step = tf.Variable(0)
```

## define the way learning rate change with different [params](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/exponential_decay)

```
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.1, global_step, 500, 0.7, staircase=True)
```

## pass them to optimizer

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
```

Comment: I am in fact defining the learning rate in a similar way. I have updated my question to reflect the same.

Comment: Probably that is happend because you create global_step variable twice:
`global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='global_step')`
and
`global_step = 0`

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.

1. You are not supposed to increment the variable yourself
2. You aren't actually manually incrementing global_step, even though it may appear as if you are.

**Issue 1**

According to the documentation for [`tf.train.AdamOptimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer#apply_gradients), calling `minimize()` is short-hand for calling `compute_gradients()` and `apply_gradients()`. What you actually get returned into your `optm` variable is:

> An `Operation` that applies the [...] gradients. If `global_step` was not None, that operation also increments `global_step`.

What this means is that the value stored for the `global_step` (`tf.Variable`) will be incremented when you call `sess.run(optm)`.

**Issue 2**

After the first line of the given code, you have a variable called `global_step` which is a `tf.Variable` object. Importantly, it doesn't have a numeric value; it's just a reference to an object which will *provide* a numeric value *when* you run `sess.run`.

In order to make graph building convenient, Tensorflow allows operations like this:

```
a = tf.constant(1)
b = a + 2
```

At which point, the variable `b` will be a **new Tensor object**. We could run `sess.run(b)` and get the actual value out (after initializing, of course), but `b` is an **object**, not a value. When you run `global_step += 1` it's creating a **new Tensor object**, which, when you `sess.run` it, will do some calculation and give you back a number.

So, at `global global_step`, you still have a reference to the `tf.Variable` tensor, but after the first loop, your `global_step` will refer to:
a tensor which, when put through `sess.run`, will give you the result of adding 1 to your original tf.Variable object.

After the second loop, your `global_step` refers to a tensor which will give you the result of adding 1 to the result of adding 1 to your original tf.Variable object.

As you loop through, you are adding operations and referring to the new result, but never actually changing the value stored for the `tf.Variable` object. This is why when you run `sess.run(global_step)`, you get the number you expected, while the actual variable value never changes.